# Suma de n cantidad de numeros en Bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash, bucles, consola, terminal

Estoy haciendo una calculadora que me permita hacer las operaciones basicas pero esta calculadora me debe de sumar la cantidad de datos que el usuario quiera agregarle(k1+k2+..+kn). Cuando ingreso los datos me doy cuenta que no me omite los espacios por ende no puedo sumar numeros que sean decenas, centenas, etc. solo unidades y el otro punto es que no me permite ingresar fracciones, decimales ni numeros negativos.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
numeros=0
read numeros
while [ $numeros -gt 0]
do
     rem=`expr $numeros %10`
     suma=`expr $suma +rem`
     numeros=`expr $numeros / 10`
done
echo "La suma de todos los digitos es: $suma"
exit 0
```

Esta es la forma que me deja ingresar los numeros.
[image: ImagenConsola]
Esta es la forma como quiero ingresar los numeros 
[image: ImagenConsola2]

Comment: Que intentas hacer con `rem=expr $numeros %10` y `numeros=expr $numeros / 10`? Porque quieres el modulo y porque dividirlos por 10?

Comment: Hola, estas lineas son necesarias para poder realizar la suma ya que si las quito no me deja hacer la suma, Se queda en espera y nunca hace la operacion

Comment: Es que no tienen sentido. Puedes explicar que quires que te hagan? Dado que tu `$numeros` es un string con espacios, no puedo entender que quieres hacer con ellas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que te da es por cómo bash interpreta el token `[`.

El token `[` es un operador que tiene que ser terminado con otro token `]`. Los token se dividen por un separador, en este caso se utiliza el espacio, es decir, es diferente `0]` que `0 ]` ya que en el segundo caso hay un espacio entre los dos caracteres y ahora si se concluye el evaluador `]`, por lo que tu sentencia debería ser de la forma `while [ $numeros -gt 0 ]`.

Respecto a tu sumadora, puedes hacer que, por comodidad, esta separe lo deseado por el caracter que desees, en este caso puede ser `+`.

Un script útil para aprender (pero ineficiente por la naturaleza de `bash`) que puedes usar es este. Documento lo que hago dentro del código. Lo puedes copiar y pegar y funcionará tal cual.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

export s_resultado=""

#  Ambos prompt los defino con un caracter, puedes hacer 
#+ uso de otro u otros.
declare -r _prompt=">"       # Declaramos "_prompt" de solo lectura, puedes cambiar esto.
export _prompt

declare -r _resp_prompt=">"  # Declaramos "_resp_prompt" de solo lectura, puedes cambiar esto.
export _resp_prompt

sumar() {
: << __sumar__

        Suma todos los campos separados por el caracter '+'. Estos campos
    provienen de la sentencia en la funcion "calcular" y se ingresan
    como un array de parametros en esta funcion.

        De esta manera tambien se podria hacer una funcion como un 
    "multiplicar" pero usando el caracter '*' en lugar del de '+'.

__sumar__

    while read -d '+' sumando || [[ -n "$sumando" ]] 
              #  Puedes quitar el delimitador "+" y el parametro "-d" 
              #+ para que busque lo separado entre espacios.
    do
        ((s_resultado+=sumando))
    done <<< "$@"
}

calcular() {
: << __calcular__

        Se encarga de ser una funcion principal que podria mandar a
    llamar funciones previas a la suma con motivos de limpieza o 
    validacion de datos.

__calcular__

    sentencia="$1"

    egrep -q '[^0-9\+\ \-]' <<< "$sentencia"
    #               |
    #               |______ Estos son los caracteres permitidos. Numericos,
    #                       "+", espacios y "-".

    # De lo contrario arroja un error sin terminar el programa.
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] \
        && echo "Ingresa unicamente numeros separados por +" \
        && return


    sentencia="$(tr -s "+" <<< "$sentencia")"  # Elimina los caracteres '+' repetidos.

    # Analiza si hay cadenas de la forma '+', osea, simplemente con el signo mas.
    [[ "$sentencia" =~ (^\+$) ]] \
        && echo "Error" \
        && return

    # Una vez limpiados y validados los datos, se procede a operar.
    sumar $sentencia

    echo "$_resp_prompt $s_resultado"
    s_resultado=""
}

sumadora() {

    while :
    do
        echo -n "$_prompt "
        read sentencia

        [[ "$sentencia" =~ ^(q|quit|exit|salir)$ ]] && exit
        #                           |
        #                           |______ Sale con alguna de estas palabras.

        calcular "$sentencia"

    done
}

sumadora
```

Cuya ejecución daría algo por el estilo.

```
$ ./sumadora.sh
> 91+9+10
> 110
> 90++9++10+100
> 209
> +
Error
> +++
Error
> 90+a+10
Ingresa unicamente numeros separados por +
> 10+-10+10
> 10
> 50+-25
> 25
> q
$
```

Respecto a los puntos decimales y las fracciones, pues la relación entre ellas es semejante salvo unas diferencias. Ambos son elementos de los reales, pero una denota una operación en si misma con el operador `/`, así que al sumar fracciones también tendrías que operar previamente la división y seguir la jerarquía de operadores. Además de que los decimales utilizan el caracter `.` o `,` (según la convención que uses) y eso también se usa como delimitador.

La expansión aritmética de `bash` no es suficientemente poderosa para hacer esas operaciones por si sola, podrías implementar algo con `bash` si de verdad tienes esa obsesión, pero ello [va más allá de su utilidad como la mejor API para orquestar programas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169765#169765).

[Aquí](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks) se describe una increíble cantidad de herramientas para lograr ese cometido pasando desde la típica `bc` hasta el uso de `zsh`, `awk` y otros programas.

Sin embargo, todo lo anterior es si únicamente tienes una obsesión con `bash` (yo la tengo :) ) o si te dejaron de ejercicio hacer uso extensivo de sus capacidades, más allá de su eficiencia.

Si lo único que quieres es una calculadora interactiva con un comportamiento previo y posterior ajeno al cálculo aritmético usual, como borrar, cambiar el prompt, cambiar mensajes personalizados, puedes simplemente implementar un *wrapper* de `bc` al cual le pasas toda la cadena a operar, y eso es mucho más eficiente que delegar a `bash` todo el cálculo y el pre/post-procesamiento.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear 

declare -r _prompt=">"
export _prompt
declare -r _res_prompt=">"
export _res_prompt

export _escala="2"

calculadora() {

    while :
    do
        echo -n "$_prompt "
        read sentencia

        [[ "$sentencia" =~ ^(q|salir|quit)$ ]] && exit 

        echo "$_res_prompt" $(bc <<< "scale=$_escala; $sentencia")
        #                          |
        #                          |___ Aqui se realiza todo el calculo.
        #echo "$_res_prompt" "$(awk "BEGIN{print $sentencia}")
        #O puedes usar awk y descomentar esta linea.
    done

}

calculadora
```

Y su ejecución sería algo de la forma.

```
$ ./calculadora2.sh
> 0+10/2+0.5
> 5.50
> 10-5+10/3+0.1
> 8.43
> 2/2
> 1.00
> 3/2 + 9
> 10.50
> q
$
```

En el caso de sumar, sin tomar en cuenta fracciones, porque son operaciones en si mismas, y únicamente usando como separador los espacios, puedes usar esto.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear 

declare -r _prompt="(suma)"
export _prompt
declare -r _res_prompt="(resultado)"
export _res_prompt

sumadora() {

    while :
    do
        echo -n "$_prompt "
        read sentencia

        [[ "$sentencia" =~ ^(q|salir|quit)$ ]] && exit 

        printf "%s %s\n" \
            "$_res_prompt" \
            "$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "}{resultado+=$0}END{print resultado}' <<< "$sentencia")"
    done

}

sumadora
```

Resultando esto.

```
$ ./sumadora2.sh
(suma) 10 .5
(resultado) 10.5
(suma) 10 0.5 -1 2.5
(resultado) 12
(suma) q
$
```

Answer (score 5):

Hay varios temas con tu script. Primero, te falta un espacio antes del `]` y por eso tienes el error que ves:

```
while [ $numeros -gt 0 ]
```

y no

```
while [ $numeros -gt 0]
```

Después, usando `read` tienes que decirle cuantos variables tiene que leer. Tu lees solo uno, entonces el `-31 12 5 3` se lea como una sola entrada:

```
terdon@tpad ~ $ read numeros
-31 12.5 3
terdon@tpad ~ $ echo ":$numeros:"
:-31 12.5 3:
```

Entonces, el `[ $numeros -gt 0 ]` se convierte a `[ -31 12 5 3 -gt 0 ]` y eso te da el error.

En vez de usar read, es mas fácil (para ti y para el usuario) de pasar los valores al momento de llamar el script en vez de tener que hacerlo manualmente. Así puedes tambien volver a ejecutar lo mismo con solo dando al <kbd>↑</kbd> y <kbd>enter</kbd>. Y si quieres la suma, no entiendo porque te complicas tanto la vida:

```
#!/bin/bash
suma=0
for numero in "$@"; do
  suma=$((suma+numero))
done
echo "La suma de todos los digitos es: $suma"
```

Ejecutalo asi:

```
$ foo.sh -31 12 5 3
La suma de todos los digitos es: -11
```

---

El shell no es un lenguaje de programación "real". Tiene muchas limitaciones, entre ellas la inhabilidad de hacer matemática de decimales. Si los necesitas, toca usar otro lenguaje o hacer la matematica con otra herramienta. Por ejemplo, `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

suma=0
for numero in "$@"; do
 suma=$(echo "$suma + $numero" | bc)
done
echo "La suma de todos los digitos es: $suma"
```

Y:

```
$ foo.sh -31 12.5 3
La suma de todos los digitos es: -15.5
```

---

Si insistes en hacerlo leyendo los datos después de ejecutar, puedes hacer algo como:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

## lee los numeros en un array
read -a numeros;

suma=0
for numero in "${numeros[@]}"; do
  suma=$(echo "$suma + $numero" | bc)
done
echo "La suma de todos los digitos es: $suma"
```

Comment: A lo que yo intento llegar es que primero tengo me mostrar un menu en el cual el usuario al momento de seleccionar la opcion de suma este le limpie la consola y le permita ingresar los numeros y que haga la operacion de suma.

Comment: @MynorJosueUrrutiaJimenez entonces puedes usar un array. Acabo de ponerte un ejemplo.